# How to change skin to Batman Beyond?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I've finished Batman Arkham City (now with 63% complete yet), and I still don't have any option to change the skin.

How can I change my default Batman skin to Batman Beyond (or other skins) ?

Comment: Also, as a sidenote, a Adam West skin would be funny!

Comment: what a brilliant idea :D

Comment: @Machado: I’d pay money for that, especially if Batman’s dialogue got recorded by (and rewritten for) Adam West too. “The nobility of the almost-human porpoise.”

Comment: @Paul, me too! Batman with a belly, knocking down enemies with a Robin talking to him "Holy thugs, Batman" would be priceless!

Comment: @Machado: and once you get to a certain combo level, each punch is visually punctuated with **ZAP**, **KA-POW** etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before completing the game, you can only change skins in the challenge rooms, after completing the game you have the chance to pick your Batman skin before loading your normal game or new game plus.

Edit: You can change skins before completing the game by entering this cheat code, I don't know if disables achievements/trophies or not, though

> Press the following combination on the Main Menu screen (after you have selected your save slot):
>
> - Left, Left, Down, Down, Left, Left, Right, Up, Up, Down

Comment: I beat the game, but loading my old game don't show me any option to change the skin. Is it really necessary to have de skins DLC to see this option ?

Comment: You'll need to download at least one skin DLC to see that option. If you got the Catwoman DLC and you start any of her completed chapters, you'll see the option to change her skin as well

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the skin's DLC first of all (it doesn't come with the game by default).  If you don't have that yet, the cheapest/easiest way you can get one is through Nos's rewards program (google it).  If you can't find any Nos near you, you could also buy one on eBay for a few bucks.

Assuming you have the DLC downloaded and installed, ...

According to [a post on some forums](http://community.batmanarkhamcity.com/forums/showthread.php/8638-How-do-you-change-your-skins-in-Batman-Arkham-City?highlight=change%20skin), you need to go to where you select New Game Plus and press A.

Answer (score 2):

You can't buy the Batman Beyond outfit anymore on its own, you either have to buy a complete skins pack or The Arkham Bundle (which also has Nightwing and Robin [Robin has his own skins!] and all of the other skins) However if you want a free skin, the Batman Inc. Batsuit is available for free.