# Can't change Batman skin with code

Tags: batman-arkham-city, cheats

I'm trying to change the skin on Batman Beyond Arkham City by using this code and it doesn't work.

> Press the following combination on the Main Menu screen (after you
>   have selected your save slot):
>
> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd>

I can hear the sound to confirm that I entered the right code, but on the next screen I don't get the choice of skins. I want to change into the Batman Beyond costume, which i purchased.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Have an upvote because I like the title of this question.

Comment: Can you check out the duplicate and see if following instructions there fixes this for you?

Answer (score 1):

You have to finish the game before you can get that option.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question: [How to change skin to Batman Beyond?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34757/how-to-change-skin-to-batman-beyond)

It should be mentioned that at least in the Joker's challenge rooms you can change your costume before finishing the game.